# Mark CMake package as required by some targets, not others

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake file that contains a target that depend on a package, namely Java, as well a target that dose not require Java. 
I would like to be able to build the not-requiring-java target w/o requiring java.

```
add_executable(nojava_targ "")
add_executable(java_targ "")
```

The trouble is once CMake sees the requiring-java-project on a machine w/o Java, CMake errors out, refusing to build the Makefile. This prevents the not-requiring-java target from building even though it doesn't need java.

```
find_package(JNI COMPONENTS Development)

target_include_directories( java_targ PRIVATE 
   ${JTARG_INCLUDES}
   ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
/mnt/src/prjx/JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH
  used as include directory in directory /mnt/src/prjx/
```

Is there some way to signal to CMake that this package is required, but only by some targets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find_package will set JNI_FOUND to true if it finds the package, so add any Java-target 
commands only if JNI_Found is true. Something like this:

```
find_package(JNI COMPONENTS Development)
if(JNI_FOUND)
    add_executable(java_targ java_targ.cpp)
    target_include_directories(java_targ PRIVATE 
        ${JTARG_INCLUDES}
        ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})        
endif()
```